# sinon stub on global function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon, sinon-chai

I try to stub any global function: `function randomNumber(min, max){/*...*/}` (`window.randomNumber === randomNumber`) but when I create stub in test case `sinon.stub(window, 'randomNumber')` and mocks result `randomNumber.returns(1);)` it doesn't work and call original 'randomNumber' (`window.randomNumber !== randomNumber`), why?

---

[EDIT]

Part of my code: https://plnkr.co/edit/GAaxA3iN8QehDN7HbOc8?p=preview (it is interesting it's works in browser, in console throw `undefined is not a function (evaluating 'randomNumber.onCall(0)')`)
and `package.json`:

`"chai": "^3.5.0",
"karma": "^1.7.0",
"karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
"karma-sinon-chai": "^1.3.1",
"mocha": "^3.4.1",
"phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.14",
"sinon": "^2.2.0",
"sinon-chai": "^2.10.0",
"sinon-stub-promise": "^4.0.0"`

Comment: Check that `window.randomNumber` can be overridden in principle and report to us here in comments.

Comment: I can't override `window.randomNumber` after stub created

Comment: 1) `const originalRandomNumber = window.randomNumber`. 2) `window.randomNumber = function () { console.log("Overridden!") }`. 3) `console.log(window.randomNumber === originalRandomNumber)`. <- If it prints `false` then it was overridden (without `sinon` yet). What does it print?

Comment: I create blank test case and paste there steps above, it prints `false`.

Comment: Write a minimal script that reproduces your issue and add it to the question, also add what packages w/ versions it needs to work, so we may reproduce it and troubleshoot.

Comment: I added code and package.json dependencies

Comment: In Node.js: 1) there is no `window` object, 2) calling `randomNumber` is identical to calling `global.randomNumber` not `window.randomNumber` as it is in browser. `randomNumber` is undefined in Node, because `randomNumber` is not the same as `window.randomNumber`. You may share your __Node.js__ code via https://runkit.com

Comment: Yes, but when I run tests in phantomjs, window object is defined

Comment: Someone sorted this out? @Alcadur? I'm facing the same issue right now after upgrading Karma/Sinon/etc to latest version. I do `sinon.stub(window, 'foo').value(123)` but then from my JS code using `foo` yields `undefined`, although using `window.foo` correctly gives `123` but i'm not going to rewrite my whole codebase...